# Why does Ubuntu go on disconnection fits?

Tags: networking

Got a new router (Netgear DGN2200) and wireless performance has been woeful, with disconnection fits happening several times a day - it disconnects out of the blue, and then fails to connect indefinitely - saying authentication timed out, or the firmware crashes and etc.

Here is a system log demonstrating the frequency of the issue: http://paste.ubuntu.com/705613/

Does anyone have any ideas? Launchpad unfortunately has not been helpful.

My wireless card is a mobile one: Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection [8086:4229] (rev 61)

I've found that killing wpa_supplicant seems to help stop it from looping like that.

Comment: Can you add some information about your wireless card? http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: If it is a new router, are you sure that Ubuntu is the problem?  I've seen some routers that seem to grind to a halt after a while (probably due to memory exhaustion) and you can only restore the wireless functionality by rebooting them.  If rebooting the router makes your Ubuntu system behave better, then this may be the case.

Comment: I'm certain, because it seems killing wpa_supplicant seems to stop the issue and allows it to reconnect. I also have other computers connected to the router, and their connection works fine when my laptop is having issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded to 11.10 and the issue *seems* to have been done away with.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with James. Test that Ubuntu is the issue before blaming it.

1. Stick another known-to-work system on the network (eg another Ubuntu machine, a smartphone, Windows PC or Mac). You may have done this already but you haven't said as much.
2. If James is right, high-peer-connection bittorrent traffic is great for knocking over a faulty router with memory issues (or just a bad one). You can do it legally too, just download Ubuntu over bittorrent a few times.
3. Rarely (happened once to me since I started playing with WiFi) a particular network card and router just won't get along. Try another network card if Ubuntu was working fine before (and other systems work)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall `network-manager` and install `wicd`

I had faced a similar issue when I upgraded from 9.10 to 10.04. `network-manager` was constantly dropping the wireless connection. In this respect `wicd` has been far better. While my laptop still drops the connection it automatically resumes the connection (the auto resumption works 99 times out of 100). Another confounding factor is the age of my router (very old) but `wicd` still had better performance than `network-manager`